# I deployed a Next.js Prisma mongoDB project on Vercel. Locally if I update or delete my DB, it works But doesn't work on production

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel

Locally or in production if I update or delete my DB, it works locally But doesn't work or show the updates on production. Whenever I redeploy the updates shows. What can be the solution?
my app link: https://issue-tracker-pi-virid.vercel.app/issues
github repo: https://github.com/rahin21/issue-tracker

I tried to use build command
`npx prisma generate` and `npx prisma db push`
I also used the command below. But which is only used for SQL and postgreSQL
`npx prisma migrage deploy`